# IE8 script error 800704a6?

Tags: windows-xp, internet-explorer, internet-explorer-8, javascript

We have a user who suddenly started getting the following error when trying to open some web apps using window.open from within an embedded web browser in our software

[image: Error Message]

The script uses javascript's window.open command, and it works absolutely fine if I copy/paste the URL directly into IE. It only fails when run from within our application. I'm fairly sure it's a security setting of some kind... I've googled the error and tried all the suggestions I can find about IE settings but with no luck. The only thing I haven't tried is disabling Protected Mode because that setting doesn't seem to exist on XP.

Her PC Windows XP running IE8, and plenty of other people at the office have similar setups which run fine. I've gotten the error to go away a few times by reinstalling IE8, but it always comes back a few days later. I think its a software update of some kind, but I don't see any software updates in Add/Remove programs.

Does anyone have any ideas as to how I can make this go away?

Comment: You try this one: http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/iewebdevelopment/thread/4357c254-d571-4166-bd62-ca7f21be121a ?

Comment: I already tried all the suggestions listed on that site

Comment: Is the error always on "Line 18, Char 2"? If so can you post the script (or at least the lines around there)?

Comment: The error line always points to the `window.open` javascript line

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The only information I've been able to find on this error is from [Josh Poley's MSDN blog](https://web.archive.org/web/20111008191141/http://blogs.msdn.com:80/b/joshpoley/archive/2008/01/04/errors-007-facility-win32.aspx).

> 1190 0x800704A6 A system shutdown has already been scheduled. ERROR_SHUTDOWN_IS_SCHEDULED

However, the message implies that you get this when trying to schedule a shutdown. The only thing I can think of is that an installation/Windows update is waiting for a reboot.

<strike>You say that you can't see updates in Add/Remove programs - have you checked the "Show updates" option is checked?</strike>

Other posts that mention this error are similar in nature to yours.

Comment: Yes the "Show Updates" option is checked. There are a few updates listed, but they were all installed weeks ago while the problem only started happening a few days ago. I got it working once deleting one of the updates and rebooting, however the problem came back a few days later (that particular update was added to a Blocked list so was not reinstalled)

Comment: However strange it may sound, a reboot did fix the problem. My mistake for assuming she had already tried that before calling me :) I am guessing an IE update got installed and the PC was waiting for a reboot... she recently got a new PC which might explain why the problem keeps coming back since our automatic update policy is to download updates when available, but to install/reboot on weekends only.

Comment: This was a problem for me and rebooting the machine fixed it.

Answer (score 1):

8 of my users were facing the same problem, but every time they used to getting a diff line no and a diff error code. After trying all the above steps I finally installed IE8 and reset the Roaming And Local Profile and luckily next day when i followed the issue. It was resolved.

Answer (score -1):

You can disable the javascript debugging notification in your IE settings. It is under tools --> internet options --> Advanced --> disable script debugging. If you check that you should no longer receive the error notifications.

Comment: I will give that a try, but won't that just hide the error? I still need the window.open command to work and show the web app